# Can vtkImageReslice be reversed?

Tags: python-3.x, vtk

I have a 3D image and an affine matrix I use vtkImageReslice in python to get the resliced numpy array. However, after I perform whatever algorithm on the resliced array, I want to revert it back to its original state. (Shape, coordinate, etc).

For example, say I performed segmentation on the resliced array, and want to save it so that it will be comparable with the image before reslicing. Is this possible?

For reference, below is part of the code that the package I am using (fury) uses vtkImageReslice. I am hoping to reverse this process.

```
image_resliced = vtk.vtkImageReslice()
set_input(image_resliced, im)
image_resliced.SetResliceTransform(transform)
image_resliced.AutoCropOutputOn()

# Adding this will allow to support anisotropic voxels
# and also gives the opportunity to slice per voxel coordinates
RZS = affine[:3, :3]
zooms = np.sqrt(np.sum(RZS * RZS, axis=0))
image_resliced.SetOutputSpacing(*zooms)

image_resliced.SetInterpolationModeToLinear()
image_resliced.Update()

vtk_resliced_data = image_resliced.GetOutput()

ex1, ex2, ey1, ey2, ez1, ez2 = vtk_resliced_data.GetExtent()

resliced = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(
    vtk_resliced_data.GetPointData().GetScalars())
```

Comment: If you wan the original image data you can just use `im.GetOuput()`

Comment: @NikhilDevadiga Yes, but I want to first get the resliced array, run some algorithm with that array and transform that output to have the same transformed state as the original image. But im.GetOuput() will just return the original image right?

Comment: Yes, it will just return the original image. I believe you strictly need to revert the process. No shortcuts are allowed

Comment: @NikhilDevadiga I see. Thank you! I'll have to figure out what exactly happens inside then.